# AngularJS: Directive scope conflicting with controllers scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm working on a project with AngularJS where I have an issue with 2 scopes conflicting:
- I have controllers defining scopes in different places of my DOM (it works great)
- I just added 3 directives to implement a "help" tooltip function just as chardin.js plugin in jQuery (http://heelhook.github.io/chardin.js/) : one main directive to be able to trigger them all at once, one 'child' directive on the trigger button, and one 'child' directive used to mark each DOM element on which I want the tooltip.

When I have only those 3 directives, it works great, but when I implement my controllers and my directives at the same time, I cannot use my controllers anymore (the scope seems to be completly wrong...)

The structure I have is something like this :

- html -> main controller
- 4 sections -> 4 controllers

and I added 1 directive on the body (the main one), 1 directive to a button somewhere, and 1 directive on various elements of the 4 sections...

I'm aware my explanations are confused, but I really did my best for my first message here!

If you want to see at the code I have written for my directives, here it is:http://plnkr.co/edit/GrwgkH?p=preview

Thanks a lot for your help

S.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your controller's scope models in some object. Primitive values (e.g., number, string, boolean) are hidden in child scopes by its own property with the same name.

Read more in [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) on AngularJS github wiki.

Comment: I've read all the docs on angular website, and I've looked at the code on github but I haven't thought about the wiki! thanks for that idea!!

Comment: And for the moment, I have 2 solutions: forget about directives, and use a service where I use angular.element.find with a test on attributes to rebuild the jquery plugin without jquery (it works perfectly but I do not like testing all the dom elements to check their attributes..)
The second idea I have, is to use directive to populate an array of elements, located in a service, and then use the service to map the array, so as to eliminate the first test of all DOM elements to find those with my attributes...

Comment: Unfortunately, my second option is not working, because I have this issue: my directive can be everywhere in the dom, and can have nested elements (the rest of the html).
But those nested elements can't have access to the initial controller which is defined above my directive!

Comment: Call me crazy, but I may have a solution...
What I need is to keep the scope of the nested dom elements to be the scope of the parent element of the directive. And that what Transclude does, except that to use a transclude, I need to define a template, and to replace my directive with this template. And the result is to embedded my directive element in a new element (a div for exemple).
Say I first have : <nav directivename>stuff here like dom elements</nav>, i will end up with a <div transcluded><nav directivename>stuff here like dom elements</nav></div> which is not very nice.

Comment: The end of my answer has been deleted, so here is the solution I've used:
I can use a controller function, and use the $transclude predefined function to implement my own transclusion method : element.append(clone)! And then I end up with the exact same dom element than before my directive... Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having issues with Primitive values as well. I ended up using sugar.js and Object.extended() to create a $scope.context object that I stored my model data on. This allowed for easy caching of the data as well.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, I'll look at sugar.js